# node is showing status as not ready. node is not working.I have already installed the node controller in other system

Tags: eucalyptus

I have run the command `euserv-describe-node-controllers` and it is showing notready. I have done all the steps and I have also registered the node but it is still not working. I am using EDGE networking.

Answer (score 0):

There are various factor which can affect the state of node . It will be easy to troubleshoot by checking nc.log in node and cloud output in CLC

Comment: In clc cloud-output.log is showing that Null parameter was passed when a non null parameter was expected and in nc.log it is showing that could not stat file //var/run/eucalyptus/eucanetd.pid